# Cannot created executables installing IT++, ACML

Tags: c++, amd-processor

I want to install IT++ with ACML

I first installed ACML and then did:
   export LDFLAGS=$LDFLAGS:"-L/opt/acml4.4.0/ifort32/lib"
   export CPPFLAGS=$CPPFLAGS:"-I/opt/acml4.4.0/ifort32/include"

So that IT++ can find it when it configures itself.

NExt I went to the IT++ directory and typed "./configure"

then I get the following error:

```
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for g++... g++
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

I went to the config.log and the interesting lines are given below:

```
    lib conftest.cpp  >&5
g++: :-I/opt/acml4.4.0/ifort32_mp/include: No such file or directory
g++: :-L/opt/acml4.4.0/ifort32_mp/lib: No such file or directory
configure:2836: $? = 1
```

Why is it doing this?